# Dynamically filling ul

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I've got some issues with the css based dropdown menu I'm building. It's built with `<ul>` and `<li>`, and I want it to be 70% of the screen, so I put the following in the css:

```
.m_wrapper {
    position:relative;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0px 0px 10px 0px;
}
.menu * {
    position:relative;
}
.m_wrapper ul {
    position:relative;
    width:70%;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:table;
    height:20px;
    padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
}
.m_wrapper li {
    position:relative;
    width:20%;
    float:left;
    padding: 5px 0px 5px 5px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    height:20px;
}
```

I have put this in a [JFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ERQSn/), along with some other elements which are also present on the page. The other objects are 70% as well, so I want the sides of the menu to be aligned to them. The problem is that the `<li>` don't fill the `<ul>` entirely, so the right side is unaligned. I tried making the list items wider, but then when it looked good on one screen the items were too wide and therefore "jumped down" to a new row on another with smaller resolution.

I've googled the problem, and read a few questions+solutions here on StackOverflow, but nothing's worked on both screen resolutions so far and I'm out of ideas. So help would be very appreciated.

Comment: And your list items are generated dynamically correct?

Comment: Can you just drop the <li> item size from 24 to 22 like so http://jsfiddle.net/ERQSn/2/ is that what you want?

Comment: Also, your HTML structure has a massive amount of syntax errors, missing quotes, missing ending tags altogether.  Improperly nested ending tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing is because CSS `width` specifies the internal width of the element, before padding and border width is added.  You can change this with the `box-sizing` property:

```
width:25%; /* because you have four menu items */
box-sizing:border-box; /* include border width and padding in element width */
-moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* For FF */
```

Note that `box-sizing` is [not supported in all browsers](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/).

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ERQSn/4/)

Comment: No problem.  Note that you need to use `-moz-box-sizing:border-box;` too for FireFox.  [See here for browser compatibility](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/user-interface/)

Comment: Yes, I saw that when I looked at w3schools definition. Thanks!